# How to list all folders on android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to make an app that scans my phone's memory. I know about Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). But there are also other folders on my phone, such as folders used by other applications. When I try to use the linux "du /" command, I get a permission denied error. It will work with root, but there are applications on GooglePlay like Total Commander or Termux that have the ability to scan almost all folders on the device whithout root. So how they do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Environment.getDataDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getDataDirectory()).

Comment: I tried but it only returns my app's data directory. How can I see which files are being used by other applications. For example, Spotify, if I'm not mistaken, can store music files in the data directory. Applications like DiskUsage can see these files.
How it do that? 
or 
How can I get information about the memory each application is using?